# How to remove zeroth index of array in ruby using pop function

Tags: ruby

I have an array like:

```
a = Array.new([1,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,7,8])
```

By doing the following, I expect the output to be the zeroth index, which is popped out of the array.

```
a.pop
a.pop(0)
```

I am getting the output `nil`. Please give some suggestions on this behaviour.

Comment: You are not getting `nil` but `[]`, an array with 0 elements, right?

Comment: BTW, you can just write `a = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,7,8]` to create an array.

Comment: Please use English punctuation when writing in English.

Answer (score 4):

The optional argument to [`pop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-pop) is not the index to pop from but the number of elements to pop. They are always taken from the end of the array.

To take from the beginning you need [`shift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-shift).

Answer (score 3):

`.pop` is removing elements from the right. To remove elements from the left, use `.shift`

```
a.shift
```